# Remove the comma after the URL from the bibliography

Tags: citing

I am getting a comma after the URL link in the bibliography which I want to remove since it does not belong there.

How can I remove the comma from the bibliography?

**tex file:**

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    english,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{a4}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
                    bookmarksopen=true,
                    bookmarksnumbered=true,
                    colorlinks=true,
                    citecolor=black,
                    linkcolor=black                 
                    ]
                   {hyperref}

\begin{document}

Mowing down trees, flooding streets and battering buildings, Patricia hit land as a Category 5 hurricane on Friday \cite{wazeText} evening before grinding inland. It moved quickly but lost power in the mountains that rise up along the Pacific coast and was downgraded to a tropical depression on Saturday morning as it headed through central \cite{restRoy} Mexico \cite{jdkWiki}.

        \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**bibliography**

```
    @misc{wazeText,
         author = {Wikipedia},
         title = {Waze},
         howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waze}},
  note = {Accessed: 06.11.2015}
}

@misc{restRoy,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {{Representational state transfer}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer}},
  note = {Accessed: 07.11.2015}
}

@misc{jdkWiki,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {{Java Development Kit}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit}},
  note = {Accessed: 06.11.2015}
}

    @misc{waze,
         author = {androidcommunity},
         title = {Waze traffic app updates with {Foursquare} and {Yelp} integration},
         howpublished = {\url{http://androidcommunity.com/waze-traffic-app-updates-with-foursquare-and-yelp-integration-20120131/}},
  note = {Accessed: 29.09.2015}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use package `a4`.

Comment: Honestly, i would use package `biblatex` to do the job. On the other hand, though wikipedia does the export in that way, wikipedia cannot be the author of a wikipedia entry.

Comment: You added another entry. Here as well, androidcity provides the information, but is not the author. But for a blog-post an author is often well defined, in this case, it is [Michael Crider](http://androidcommunity.com/author/michael/).

Comment: @Johannes_B: I found this article which describes how to cite from Wikipedia in Latex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: At this page, it stands Wikipedia as the author  in the misc entry.

Comment: You are completely right. The information really is there and is contradictory to every other style they describe. I recommend to use `Wikipedia contributors` as the author.

Answer (score 3):

You saw the warning that the year is missing in your bib entrys?  Adding them everything works as you want.  You can use `url` instead of `howpublished`.

Please see the mwe:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{wazeText,
  author       = {Wikipedia},
  title        = {Waze},
  year         = {2015},
  url          = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waze},
  note         = {Accessed: 06.11.2015},
}

@misc{restRoy,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {{Representational state transfer}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer}},
  year = {2015},
  note = {Accessed: 07.11.2015},
}

@misc{jdkWiki,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {{Java Development Kit}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit}},
  note = {Accessed: 06.11.2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  11pt,
  english,
  twoside,
  a4paper,
  headsepline,
  footsepline
]{scrbook}

%\usepackage{a4}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[%
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black                 
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Mowing down trees, flooding streets and battering buildings, Patricia hit land as a Category 5 hurricane on Friday \cite{wazeText} evening before grinding inland. It moved quickly but lost power in the mountains that rise up along the Pacific coast and was downgraded to a tropical depression on Saturday morning as it headed through central \cite{restRoy} Mexico \cite{jdkWiki}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: I have added a new entry where I have noticed that it worked for it before.  Is there any explanation why did it work for the last entry and did not it work for the other 3 entries? Please take a look at my edited question. Since note and year have the same meaning?

Comment: What does year mean in the entry? does it mean when the homepage was created or accessed as note?